# Кулер GPU и windows 10

Tags: железо

Есть видеокарта GTX750M. Недавно заметил, что кулер на ней не вращается даже при высоких температурах(до 90+).
Запитал от матери - кулер крутится - проблема не в пыли и не в подшипнике. Решив, что проблема в схеме питания на плате, отдал в сервис, где мне сказали, что у них все работает. На моей матери, но с их HDD. Принес домой, запустил - ничего. Запустился с юсб-убунты и действительно - кулер начинает крутиться сразу, при 40 градусах. Ладно, загружаюсь обратно на винду - крутится, но почти сразу останавливается.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
Драйвера обновлены, через спидфан до кулера не достучаться, ничего не разгонялось, windows переустанавливал, откатывать дрова пробовал.

Comment: В BIOSе были? И какая модель мамки? Узнайте в сервисе с какой системы запускали.

Comment: Ноутовский BIOS, по-дефолту, очень ограничен: кроме вкладок с безопасностью и бутом нет ничего. Мать lenovo VIQY0Y1(чипсет и биос обновлены). В сервисе пользовали 10ку.

Comment: Кулер начинает вращаться при уходе в перезагрузку(но не при 97 градусах...). Также, можно раскрутить ненадолго стандартной приблудой "Удаление пыли".

Answer (score -1):

На 1070гтх есть такая тема, но: крутиться начинает с 56 С. Или при ребуте. Я на десктопной машине проверял
Upd есть мнение что дело в датчике регулировки скорости вращения. Но лучше железного спеца спросить на эту тему. Сам вопрос легко гуглится по "не крутится вентилятор на видеокарте nvidia". Надеюсь эта инфа вам поможет .